# How can I use the Aggregate function to aggregate summed functions?

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I have a function which takes an IEnumerable and does a GroupJoin to build a string. This works great with a simple sum in the GroupJoin.
I need to change this so the values are not just summed, but also cumulative.

I think I need to add an Aggregate function to the line of code: item.Sum(x => x.Amount)

```
IEnumerable<Items> items = {.....};
var list = Enumerable.Range(7, 6).Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 6))
    .GroupJoin(
        items,
        range => range,
        item => item.TransactionDate.Value.Month,
        (range, item) => string.Concat(
            //Example of string output: { t: "03 Jul 2018", y: 44 }, 
            "{ t: \"",
            new DateTime(
                range > 6 ? 2018 : 2019,
                range,
                1).ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
            "\", y: ",
            item.Sum(x => x.Amount).ToString(),
            " }"
          ))
     .ToArray();
```

Current result: Returns a string for example:   { t: "01 Jul 2018", y: 3 }, { t: "01 Aug 2018", y: 4 }, { t: "01 Sep 2018", y: 1 }

Required result: Return a string where the values at y are cumulative. For example: { t: "01 Jul 2018", y: 3 }, { t: "01 Aug 2018", y: 7 }, { t: "01 Sep 2018", y: 8 }

Comment: Can you provide example data for the items collection? I expect the function to group the items by month and return each month once. Or should your example look like this:  { t: "01 Jul 2018", y: 3 }, { t: "01 Aug 2018", y: 4 }, { t: "01 Sep 2018", y: 1 } ?

Comment: You are correct. The months are grouped so there is a single value for each month. Currently just the total for each month is outputted, but I need the cumulative total. I have updated the example results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group Join is a good way to solve your problem, but we should keep it readable (and avoid multiple iterations for the items collection).

Therefore I will not use an Aggregate inside the join.

```
var groups = Enumerable.Range(7, 6).Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 6)).GroupJoin(
            items,
            m => m,
            i => i.TransactionDate.Value.Month,
            (m, itemCol) => new { month = m, items = itemCol }); //Create anonymous type with month and items property.


    List<string> outputs = new List<string>(); //Contains your output
    int sum = 0;

    foreach (var group in groups) //Iterate the groups
    {
        sum += group.items.Sum(i => i.Amount);
        outputs.Add( //I used string.Format for readability. Does not change functionality
            string.Format("{{ t: \"{0}\", y: {1} }}",
                new DateTime(group.month > 6 ? 2018 : 2019, group.month, 1).ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
                sum));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If is possible to do this using an aggregate. IMHO it looks horrible, not easy to understand, difficult to test and to maintain:

TAccumulate Aggregate(IEnumerable)

- TSource: sequence of Amounts `IEnumerable<int>`
- TAccumulate: sequence with totals `IEnumerable<int>`
- So start with empty `List<int>`
- Every iteration step: add one total to the sequence of totals

.

```
// first extract the amounts:
IEnumerable<int> amountTotals = itemsInGroup.Select(item => item.Amount)
// Then aggregate.
.Aggregate(new List<int>()            // Seed with empty list

    // every iteration: add a new Total to the TAccumulate and return this TAccumulate:
    (tAccumulate, newItem) => 
    {
         tAccumulate.Add(newItem);
         return tAccumulate;
    })
```

### Neater solution

It would look much neater if you'd create extension functions:

- one to convert your range value to the DateTime text representation
- one to convert the Items joined to this range to a sequence of totals.

Let's write some extension functions, so you can use them as LINQ-like statements.
See [extension methods demystified](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Convert a range value to its DateTime string representation

```
static string ToDateTimeText(this int rangeValue)
{
    return $"t: \"{new DateTime(range > 6 ? 2018 : 2019, range, 1):dd MMM yyyy}\"";
}
```

Convert a sequence to integers to a sequence of Totals.
For example: the sequence {3, 4, 5, 10} => {3, 7, 12, 22}

```
static IEnumerable<int> ToTotals(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
     // TODO: exception if source null

     // try to get the first element of the input sequence
     var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator;
     if (enumerator.MoveNext())
     {   // first item fetched; yield return first item
         int total = enumerator.Current;
         yield return total;
         // calculate the rest:
         while (enumerator.MoveNext())
         {   // there is a next item: Calculate total and yield return
             total += enumerator.Current;
             yield return total;
         }
     }
     // else: empty input sequence empty, output is empty
}
```

Now that we have those to functions, your groupBy ResultSelector will be simple:

```
(rangeValue, itemsWithThisRangeValue) => new
{
    Date = rangeValue.ToDateTimeText(),
    AmountTotals = itemsWithThisRangeValue
       .Select(item => item.Amount)
       .ToTotals(),
}
```

Comment: I like this. Thanks a lot. The 'neater solution' almost works, but the ToTotals doesnt seem to be triggered and breakpoints within ToTotal dont get raised. The current output gives: "{ t: \"01 Jul 2018\", { y: myClass+<ToTotals>d__4 }"

Comment: Total does not work: there is probably an error in the string format. Debug it in a simple void-main-void program